# Can't fix an Error: Cannot resolve symbol 'OnClickListener'

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make tinder swipe but keep getting an error: Cannot resolve symbol 'OnClickListener'
I've already read some of the answers in similar questions but I couldn't fix it. Here is my code. Thnks in advance!

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.mindorks.placeholderview.SwipeDecor;
import com.mindorks.placeholderview.SwipePlaceHolderView;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener; /*Unused import statement*/
import com.mindorks.placeholderview.annotations.View;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private SwipePlaceHolderView mSwipeView;
    private Context mContext;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mSwipeView = (SwipePlaceHolderView)findViewById(R.id.swipeView);
        mContext = getApplicationContext();

        mSwipeView.getBuilder()
                .setDisplayViewCount(3)
                .setSwipeDecor(new SwipeDecor()
                        .setPaddingTop(20)
                        .setRelativeScale(0.01f)
                        .setSwipeInMsgLayoutId(R.layout.tinder_swipe_in_msg_view)
                        .setSwipeOutMsgLayoutId(R.layout.tinder_swipe_out_msg_view));


        for(Profile profile : Utils.loadProfiles(this.getApplicationContext())){
            mSwipeView.addView(new TinderCard(mContext, profile, mSwipeView));
        }

        findViewById(R.id.rejectBtn).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mSwipeView.doSwipe(false);
            }
        });

        findViewById(R.id.acceptBtn).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener/*Cannot resolve symbol 'OnClickListener'*/() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mSwipeView.doSwipe(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`findViewById(R.id.rejectBtn)` returns a `View` object, for which doesn't exist the method `setOnClickListener()`, and not a `Button`. 
You need to cast this `View` to a `Button` and then set the listener:

```
((Button) findViewById(R.id.rejectBtn)).setOnClickListener(
....
)
```